# Ler páginas web em loop convertendo para texto

Tags: html, delphi, navegador-de-internet

Preciso ler várias páginas web sucessivamente em loop, convertendo cada página para texto.

O objetivo é ler cotações de várias ações, do site Yahoo Finance, por exemplo.
Já tentei vários recursos, sendo o último o `WebBrowser`, o problema é que a partir de uma quantidade de páginas lidas acontece que:

- o programa pára de responder ou
- em algumas situações a página fica incompleta.

Já tentei também usar as funções

- function WebGetData(const UserAgent, URL: string): string;
- function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
- function WinInet_HttpGet(const Url: string): string;overload;

Sendo algumas do próprio StackOverflow (inglês ou português) mas também sem sucesso.

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você implementou ou tentou implementar?

Comment: Eu já fiz programas desse tipo com Indy. Acho que o "truque" é fazer uma pequena pausa entre uma requisição e outra pra não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Comment: Qual sua versão do Delphi?

Comment: Sobre o código, como disse, fiz várias tentativas. Então ficaria complicado postar todas.
Pausa entre as chamadas também já inseri, com Sleep().
Versão Delphi Tokyo.